# Jenkins - Trigger another pipeline job in same machine - without creating new "Executor"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to do similar thing - call "**some_job_pipeline**" from trigger pipeline and that it would be controller by parameter to execute on same or some specific Jenkins node.
If it is should be executed on same/master/parent job jenkins node - it should not create new "Executor". That if i set for "Node1" node executors count to 1 - job would run successfully (would not require 2-nd executor).

In example I have **Trigger_Main_Job** which looks something like this:

```
node("${params.JenkinsNode}") {
    stage("Stage 1") {
        ...
    }
    stage("some_job_pipeline") {
        build job: 'some_job_pipeline', parameters: []
    }
    stage("Stage 3") {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and **some_job_pipeline** which looks something like this:
boolean runOnItsOwnNode = params.JenkinsNode?.trim()

```
properties([
    parameters([
        string(name: 'JenkinsNode', defaultValue: '', description: 'Node from which to deploy. If "JenkinsNode" is not passed - then it will use parent job node.')
    ])
])

if(runOnItsOwnNode) {
    node("${params.JenkinsNode}") {
       print "Deploying from node: '${params.JenkinsNode}'"
    }
}
else {
    print "Deploying from parent job node."
    ???? THIS_IS MISSING_PART ????
}
```

**Note:** Similar question, but it point out that parent pipeline should be changed: [Jenkins pipeline: how to trigger another job and wait for it without using an extra agent/executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099269/jenkins-pipeline-how-to-trigger-another-job-and-wait-for-it-without-using-an-ex/59559773#59559773).  Question is is it possible to implement this and how without changing "Trigger" job. That I could create "some_job_pipeline" which execution would depend only on JenkinsNode passed parameter and not Parent/Called job implementation.

I tried to different variants to specify "???? THIS_IS MISSING_PART ????" code part in 
    node("master") {...}
and without "note" and similar things. But no luck - "some_job_pipeline" still consumes/requires new executor.